# What are the steps to update dependencies when using Gradle (Signing) Dependency Verification?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, checksum, signing

There is an excellent guide on how to setup dependency verification using Gradle in the link below:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_verification.html

In short, the initial setup is as simple as running the following bootstrap command:

```
./gradlew --write-verification-metadata pgp,sha256
```

However there are no steps provided for what to do after that, such as when you need to update a dependency.

Are you expected to run the bootstrap command again every time you update a dependency? This is insecure as by the gradle documentation, if something fails it will add an ignore list value:

"If, for some reason, verification fails during the generation, Gradle will automatically generate an ignored key entry but warn you that you must absolutely check what happens."

Or are you supposed to manually update the `gradle/verification-metadata.xml` file, if so what are the steps to do that?

Looking forward to someone explaining the intended flow for updating dependencies when using Gradle dependency verification.

Answer (score 1):

If you update a dependency, then the dependency verification will fail because of the updated dependency – as can be expected. You’ll get a console log like the following (here for an added Gradle plugin or a changed plugin version):

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'my-test'.
> Dependency verification failed for configuration ':classpath'
  3 artifacts failed verification:
    - de.undercouch.download.gradle.plugin-4.1.1.pom (de.undercouch.download:de.undercouch.download.gradle.plugin:4.1.1) from repository Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    - gradle-download-task-4.1.1.jar (de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.1) from repository Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    - gradle-download-task-4.1.1.pom (de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.1) from repository Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  If the artifacts are trustworthy, you will need to update the gradle/verification-metadata.xml file by following the instructions at https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/dependency_verification.html#sec:troubleshooting-verification
  
  Open this report for more details: file:///home/chriki/my-test/build/reports/dependency-verification/at-1625085802054/dependency-verification-report.html
```

If you then open the mentioned HTML report, you’ll see a table like the following:

| Module | Artifact | Problem(s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| de.undercouch.download:de.undercouch.download.gradle.plugin:4.1.1 | de.undercouch.download.gradle.plugin-4.1.1.pom | Checksums are missing from verification metadata |
| … | … | … |

(The original table is nicer and has clickable columns which reveal more details.)

In addition, the HTML report contains the following “Troubleshooting” section:

> Please review the errors reported above carefully. Click on the icons near to the error descriptions for information about how to fix a particular problem. It is recommended that you edit the verification file manually. However, if you are confident that those are false positives, Gradle can help you by generating the missing verification metadata. In this case, you can run with the following command-line:
>
> ```
> gradle --write-verification-metadata sha256 help
> ```
>
> In any case you **must review the result** of this operation.

So, yes, you can run the bootstrap command again after having updated a dependency. It will then update the `verification-metadata.xml` file by *adding* the new/updated dependencies as trusted. Just as in the actual bootstrap phase, you must review the results – as also clearly stated by the HTML report. You can do this, for example, by committing the `verification-metadata.xml` to your VCS before you run the bootstrap command. After having run the command, you then compare the VCS version with the locally updated version to make sure that only the upgraded dependencies (and maybe their transitive dependencies) were added but no other components.

BTW, the [“Bootstrapping dependency verification” section](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/dependency_verification.html#sec:bootstrapping-verification) of the Gradle docs also states that the bootstrap command can be used for updates (highlighting by me):

> Bootstrapping can either be used to create a file from the beginning, or **also to update an existing file with new information.**

Comment: If one of the packages had been tampered with, wouldn't running the bootstrap command just whitelist the package and therefore defeat the point of signing?

Comment: Absolutely, but wasn’t your question specifically about “updating dependencies”? Of course, you should only run the bootstrap command right after (a) you have run a _successful_, unchanged build and (b) the desired dependency upgrade just afterwards. If (a) already indicates verification failures, then you mustn’t proceed with (b); instead you must troubleshoot the failure first (e.g., as indicated in [the docs for incorrect checksums](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/dependency_verification.html#incorrect_checksums)).

Comment: That said, as noted in the answer, you _must_ review the results of the bootstrap command. I’ve updated my answer with an example for how this could easily be done. Let me know if this makes sense :-)